# Where I must set the SOAP Reference in my 3 tier architecture Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, reference, n-tier-architecture

I have a Question to the 3 tier architecture. I have a Data Layer, a Service Layer and a Display Layer. For testing I use a console. I set a reference to a soap file and I don't know where i must set the reference to the soap file (In service layer or data layer?) The soap have a lot of functions for create a guestconnection to internet.

tarasov

Comment: What's a "soap file" ? You mean the Service Reference ?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer** : Service References should always be in the `Data Tier` (as `Service Components/Agents`).

**Long answer** :

In n-tier architectures, here are the main layers :

```
[ Presentation Layer ]
[ Service Layer ]
[ Business Layer ]
[ Data Layer ]
```

The `Service Layer` is here to hide your business from the `Presentation Layer` & to give direct access to your clients through your services interfaces.

In this layer, only interfaces (and messages/services model entities) should be presents. Its **your** services representations.

Generally speaking, 3-tier is `Presentation Tier` > `Business/Logic Tier` > `Data Tier` ; there is usually no services layer elements in this one but you can put them in the logic tier.

In the `Data (Access) Layer`, you have two main data components : `Data Access Components` & `Service Components` (also known as `Service Agents`). All your references to **others** services should be here because services are "data provider".